# Change maven install download URL, or change Nexus 3 artifact URL

Tags: maven, installation, uri, nexus

My company, internally, currently switches to using Nexus 3 (run on Docker) as a repository management tool. As part of that, I migrated the inner-company Maven artifacts to Nexus, using the following curl command:

```
curl -v -u adminUsername:adminPassword \ 
--upload-file artifact.pom \ 
http://my-nexus-server/repository/maven-releases/groupId/artifactId/version/artifactId-version.pom
```

This command worked, and all files were successfully uploaded to Nexus. However, when a `groupId` had several parts (e.g. `org.apache.maven.plugins`), I (mistakenly) didn't convert the points of the `groupId` into slashes. And so, I've ended up with a URL similar to this:

`http://my-nexus-server/repository/maven-releases/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/1.2.3/maven-javadoc-plugin-1.2.3.pom`

And that turned out to be a problem, because when Maven read the `pom.xml` file, it converted the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId> org.apache.maven.plugins </groupId>
    <artifactId> maven-javadoc-plugin </artifactId>
    <version> 1.2.3 </version>
</dependency>
```

To the following URL:

`http://my-nexus-server/repository/maven-releases/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/1.2.3/maven-javadoc-plugin-1.2.3.pom`

So, I need to do one of two things:

- Find a way to tell maven (preferably in `settings.xml`) to **not** convert points to slashes for the `groupId`, when running `mvn install`.
- Mass-change URIs in a Nexus repository. (I'll take single-artifact URI changes too)

For the record, we're using Nexus 3 and Maven 3. The Maven repository in Nexus is a Maven 2 hosted repository.

Any idea on any of these tasks?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Find a way to tell maven (preferably in `settings.xml`) to **not** convert points to slashes for the groupId, when running `mvn install`.

I don’t think this is possible – let alone a good idea. Maven relies on the fact that everyone maps GAVs to URI paths the same way.

> - Mass-change URIs in a Nexus repository. (I'll take single-artifact URI changes too)

I am not aware of a way to do this.

If you can, however, start from scratch, I would **seriously** consider using [`mvn deploy:deploy-file`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) rather than a low-level tool like `curl`. Something like

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=... -DpomFile=...
```

in a shell script. The `maven-deploy-plugin` will automatically extract the GAV from the given `pom.xml` and use that to construct the correct URI path; you don’t need to do this manually. Hope that helps to get your started.

Comment: It looks like that's the way to go, then (starting from scratch). Thanks for the advice!